# how to set manually css and js in ruby 2.3.3 rails 5.2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

i am trying to set admin theme template in ruby on rails. so add my css and js (not custom) so how can i call that css and js in my main html file .how to re-load vendor folder in ruby on rails .

- how to load vendor folder using CMD like laravel .and also how to debugging in ror . In laravel we use 'dd()' so which command or function use in ror for debugging .

-how to get base url in ror ?

Comment: Hi ravi. You tagged your question 'ruby-on-rails-4', but in the title you mention rails 2.3.3? Rails 2.3.3 is a very old version of ror, things changed a lot since then. I think it could help if you would add as much detail as possible: "where are you trying to put the files, and so on?".

Comment: For debugging you can use 'debugger' if you have the 'debugger' gem installed.

Comment: For including stylesheets in for instance your application-layout, check: https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag and for javascript https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag

Comment: if i can change in config application.rb? @trueunlessfalse

Comment: Did you read and follow [Asset Pipeline in the Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)?

Comment: @spickermann, ravi, rails 2.x didn't have a asset pipeline, that's why I was asking which version is actually used. I don't understand what you want to change in config/application.rb ?

Comment: @trueunlessfalse sry it`s ruby 2.3.3 and rails 5.2.0

Comment: In the title the OP says he is using rails 5.2

Comment: @spickermann yes, he changed it now, it used to say 2.3.3 - but yes, all good, I agree on your advice to read the Asset Pipeline Guides..